# Why is binary file vary large compared to text?

Tags: c#, serialization, binary

I have been keeping a large set of data as TEXT records in a TEXT file:

yyyyMMddTHHmmssfff doube1 double2

However when I read it I need to parse each DateTime. This is quite slow for millions of records.

So, now I am trying it as a binary file which I created by serlializing my class.

That way I do not need to parse the DateTime.

```
    class MyRecord 
    {
           DateTime DT;
           double Price1;
           double Price2;
    }

            public byte[] SerializeToByteArray()
            {
                var bf = new BinaryFormatter();
                using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    bf.Serialize(ms, this);
                    return ms.ToArray();
                }
            }

    MyRecord mr = new MyRecord();

    outBin = new BinaryWriter(File.Create(binFileName, 2048, FileOptions.None));

   for (AllRecords) //Pseudo
    {
        mr = new MyRecord(); //Pseudo
        outBin.Write(mr.SerializeToByteArray());
    }
```

The resulting binary is on average 3 times the size of the TEXT file.

Is that to be expected?

EDIT 1

I am exploring using Protbuf to help me:

I want to do this with using USING to fit my existing structure.

```
   private void DisplayBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string fileName = dbDirectory + @"\nAD20120101.dat";

        FileStream fs = File.OpenRead(fileName);

        MyRecord tr;
        while (fs.CanRead)
        {

            tr = Serializer.Deserialize<MyRecord>(fs);

            Console.WriteLine("> "+ tr.ToString());

        }

    }
```

BUT after first record tr - full of zeroes.

Comment: The default serializers output a lot of overhead. If you wrote your stuff to the binary writer manually, you'd have a lot less.

Comment: This isn't just "a binary file" it's "a binary file using BinaryFormatter" - and a new BinaryFormatter for each record too, which will add extra overhead. That's the reason.

Comment: This has nothing to do with binary files per-se. This is specific to `BinaryFormatter`. Other binary formats will be efficient.

Comment: if you need a smart serialization  solution  you can take a look at ProtoBuf-net  https://code.google.com/p/protobuf-net/

Comment: @K.B     
The Serialize appears to go well. But then
`private void DisplayBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string fileName = dbDirectory + @"\nAUDUSD20120101.dat";

            FileStream fs = File.OpenRead(fileName);
            while (fs.CanRead)
            {

                MyRecord tr;
                tr = Serializer.Deserialize<MyRecord>(fs);

            }

        }`
I get error: No parameterless constructor found for MyRecord

Comment: that's  pretty simple deserialization  will need default  constructor so in  your class add  public MyRecord(){} please tell me if I should put this as an answer

Comment: Yes please, it looks right for me. Can you explain the last bit again. Where do I put MyRecord(){} - I already have a class called that

Comment: @K.B In the loop above I only get the first record. Calling Deserialize several just gets zeroes.

Answer (score 1):

Your archive likely has considerable overhead serializing type information with each record.

Instead, make the whole collection serializable (if it isn't already) and serialize that in one go.

Answer (score 0):

You are not storing a simple binary version of your DateTime, but an object representing those. That is much larger then simply storing your Date as Text.

If you create a class

```
class MyRecords
{
    DateTime[] DT;
    double[] Price1;
    double[] Price2;
}
```

And serialize that, it should be much smaller.

Also I guess DateTime still needs lots of space, so you can convert your DateTime to a Integer Unix Timestamp and store that.

Answer (score 0):

As Requested by the OP.

the output is not a binary file it's binary serialization of instances plus an overhead of BinaryFormatter to  allow deserialization later  for this reason you get 3 times the file large than expected 
if you need a smart serialization solution you can take a look at ProtoBuf-net https://code.google.com/p/protobuf-net/

[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7442164/c-sharp-and-net-how-to-serialize-a-structure-into-a-byte-array-using-binary) you can find a link explaining how you can achieve this

```
 [ProtoContract]
Public class MyRecord 
    {   [ProtoMember(1)]
           DateTime DT;
         [ProtoMember(2)]
           double Price1;
          [ProtoMember(3)]
           double Price2;
    }
```

Comment: Can you show how to deserialize WITHOUT using USING. Please see my edit 1

Comment: Sorry - forgot to save them!

Comment: Any reason why I might be only get first record?